# How to regex, and add "-" between words?

Tags: javascript, regex

UPDATED

I been looking around in the old interweb to see if there is any way I can regex this as part of a replace method I'm doing: str.replace(/\w[A-Z]/gm, "-")

> thisIsARegex

into this:

> this-Is-A-Regex

I tried to mess around on regex101 with matching a \w character followed by [A-Z] but failed.
Any thoughts?

Comment: "*matching a \w character followed by [A-Z] but failed*" what was the problem? That should have worked.

Comment: it replaces the matched character: thi--pina-ap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the first char can't be uppercase:

```js
var str = "thisIsARegex";
str = str.replace(/(?=[A-Z])/g, "-");
console.log(str);  // this-Is-A-Regex
```

If the first char can be uppercase:

```js
var str = "ThisIsARegex";
str = str.replace(/.(?=[A-Z])/g, "$&-");
console.log(str);  // This-Is-A-Regex
```

or

```js
var str = "ThisIsARegex";
str = str.replace(/\B(?=[A-Z])/g, "-");
console.log(str);  // This-Is-A-Regex
```

(Last snippet suggested by @Thomas.)

Comment: could to explain the why you have in () and the meaning of ?=

Comment: `(?=...)` can be read as "followed by ...". It differs from just `...` in that the matched portion of the string isn't considered part of the match. For example, while `"aaAaaAaa".replace(/[A-Z]/g, "-")` produces `aa-aa-aa`, `"aaAaaAaa".replace(/(?=[A-Z])/g, "-")` produces `aa-Aaa-Aaa`

Comment: @ikegami, a suggestion: `str.replace(/\B(?=[A-Z])/g, "-")`

Answer (score 4):

```js
var s = "thisIsARegex";
s = s.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').trim();
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

you can check regex on this page and make your own tests:
https://regexr.com/

```
// initial value
let text = "thisIsARegexText";

// select Uppercase characters
let regexPattern = /[^a-z]/g; 

// dump temp array
let newText = [];

// go through all characters, find Uppercase and replace with "-UppercaseCharacter"
for(i of text){
    newText.push(i.replace(/[^a-z]/g, "-" + i))
}

// assign the result to the initial variable
text = newText.join("");
```

Comment: Is there anyone would use this instead of the far less complex earlier solutions?